# Filling an object with particles issue

Tags: particles

[image]

When setting the collision to the bowl I initially was seeing some of the pieces of rice sliding to the bottom and falling out. Now that I've updated the scene with a different bowl I'm unable to get the rice to collide with the bowl and it goes straight through. The end result that I'm going for is simply to fill the bowl with rice.

Comment: It helped a bit duplicating the bowl. Still not 100%. I can trim some of the rice from the outside, but trying to get a nice mound of it is causing troubles.

Comment: Does it help by scaling everthing up/down, or alternatively making the inside of the bowl thicker to accommodate the weight of the rice, if its not going to be seen by the camera?

Comment: I'll give that a go and see.

Comment: It seemed to help a bit, but I was still getting particles protruding through the container.